# How to update data in vb.net using POST method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vb.net, post, methods

I have this code in my **config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'timerecords/index'

  get 'employees/index'
  get 'employees/show'
  get 'employees/new'
  get 'welcome/index'
  root :to => 'employees#new'

  resources :employees do
    get '/update_info' => 'employees#update_info'
  end
  resources :timerecords
end
```

When I tried to save new record, i have this in my **app/controllers/employees_controller.rb**

```
def create
   fname = params[:fname]
   mname = params[:mname]
   lname = params[:lname]
   contactno = params[:contactno]
   address = params[:address]
   username = params[:username]
   password = params[:password]
   status = params[:status]

   @employee= Employee.create(fname: fname, mname: mname, lname: lname,
                           contactno: contactno, address: address,
                           username: username, password: password, status: status)

   redirect_to @employee
end
```

with this code above but under the class name

```
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
```

Now, I have this for **update** under same controller

```
def update_info
   fname = params[:fname]
   mname = params[:mname]
   lname = params[:lname]
   contactno = params[:contactno]
   address = params[:address]
   username=params[:username]
   password=params[:password]
   status=params[:status]
   id=params[:id]

   @employee = Employee.find(id)

   @employee.update_attributes(id: id, fname: fname, mname: mname,
       lname: lname, contactno: contactno, address: address,
       username: username, password: password, status: status)

   redirect_to @employee
end
```

When I type the link, it will update just fine but with extra number in it. The link looks like this

http://localhost:3000/employees/0/update_info?id=39&fname=samplename&mname=samplename&lname=samplename&contactno=09236&address=sampleaddress&username=sampleuname&password=samplepass&status=ac

which the /0/ there has no meaning but when I won't put it, the update won't happen. What I am trying to do here is call the link in my vb.net code to update using POST Method but I can't update. Saving went fine but not during update.

This is my vb.net code when saving

```
  strLink = "https://dtitdtr.herokuapp.com/employees"
  strData = "fname=" + UrlEncode(txtFName.Text.Trim.ToUpper()) + "&mname=" + UrlEncode(txtMName.Text.Trim.ToUpper()) _
                  + "&lname=" + UrlEncode(txtLName.Text.Trim.ToUpper()) + "&contactno=" + UrlEncode(txtContactNo.Text.Trim) _
                  + "&address=" + UrlEncode(txtAddress.Text.Trim.ToUpper()) + "&username=" + UrlEncode(txtUsername.Text.Trim.ToUpper()) _
                  + "&password=" + UrlEncode(Encrypt(txtPassword.Text)) + "&status=" + UrlEncode("AC")
   Try
      Save(strLink, strData)
      MessageBox.Show("Your registration has been successful!", _
                                      "Registered!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
      cmdClear_Click(sender, e)
      frmMenu.Show()
      Me.Hide()
  Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(ex.Message)
  End Try
```

**Module**

```
 Public Sub Save(ByVal link As String, ByVal data As String)
    request = WebRequest.Create(link)
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials


    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postData = String.Format(data)
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length
    byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    response = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
    webRep = (CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)


    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)

    reader.Close()
    response.Close()

End Sub
```

I tried this for **update** but it just won't work.

```
request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:3000/employees/40/update_info?")
```

no update will happen...as if it did not execute...and if username does not exist, it adds immediately even when I was trying to update info and not add.
I guess the problem is in my **RAILS** code. I just can't figure what. *Can anyone help me?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this answer... I changed my routes.rb to this

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get 'timerecords/index'

   get 'employees/index'
   get 'employees/show'
   get 'employees/new'
   get 'welcome/index'
   root :to => 'employees#new'

   post '/update_info'
   resources :employees, :timerecords
end
```

and have my vb code this way...

```
request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:3000/employees/update_info")
```

and made sure that **id** is added in the elements. :)